# How to change color for the numbers based on its value using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to apply colors to variable count based on its value using javascript.

what i am trying to do?
The value of variable count is dynamic it can have values below 0 or greater than 0.

so now when the count value is

```
0 color should be red
1 color should be yellow
greater than 1 color should be green
less than 0 meaning negative integers like -1, -2 so on color should be grey
```

I have the code below which changes color based on value.

```
const countColor = (count: number) => {
    const colors = [red, yellow];
    return colors[count] || green;
};
```

So the above code works for count values being 0 , 1 and value greater than 1. how do i change the above code such that it handles or changes count value to grey color when value is less than 0

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using a simple `if` statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use terrnary operator that returns `grey` if `count` is less than zero otherwise returns `colors[count]` or `green` if `colors[count]` is `undefined`

```
const countColor = (count: number) => {
    const colors = ['red', 'yellow'];
    return count < 0 ? 'grey' : (colors[count] || 'green');
};
```

Comment: This just makes the code super confusing to read. Remember to also code for humans, not only machines. Another developer reading this code will need a lot of mental processing power to see what simple goal is trying to be achieved here.

Comment: how is this code difficult to read? its a simple ternary operator that returns `grey` if `count` is less than zero otherwise returns `colors[count]` or `green` if `colors[count]` is undefined.

Comment: It's a combination of a ternary, with an if-statement-converted-to-array, topped of with a default fallback.

Comment: What's wrong with just simple `if` statements? Don't try to build further on his confusing code. Help him see that the answer is much more simple, as he probably got his own snipper from a tutorial.

Comment: if his code is confusing to you, i don't know what to say to you.

Comment: a quote from Martin Fowler: “Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.”

Comment: i am gonna end this argument by saying that you are entitled to your opinion. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to forget the `[red, yellow]` array and just process count to return the color:

```
const countColor = (count: number) => {
    if (count < 0) return grey;
    else if (count > 1) return green;
    else if (count === 0) return red;
    else if (count === 1) return yellow;
};
```

Comment: I would even argue to not have a default `else`, but rather convert the last `else` to an `else if` as well, for clarity.

Comment: We could also sort them and add comments, but I hope that's clear enough with the last `else if` :)